# TensorFlow different input and output shapes for stateful LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, lstm-stateful

I would like to create a 'Sequential' model (a Time Series model as you might have guessed), that takes `20` days of past data with a feature size of `2`, and predict `1` day into the future with the same feature size of `2`.

I found out you need to specify the batch size for a stateful LSTM model, so if I specify a batch size of `32` for example, the final output shape of the model is `(32, 2)`, which I think means the model is predicting `32` days into the future rathen than `1`.

How would I go on fixing it?

Also, asking before I arrive to the problem; if I specify a batch size of `32` for example, but I want to predict on an input of shape `(1, 20, 2)`, would the model predict correctly or what, since I changed to batch size from `32` to `1`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify batch_size. But you should feed 3-d tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Sequential
features = 2
dim = 128
new_model = Sequential([
  LSTM(dim, stateful=True, return_sequences = True),
  Dense(2)
])

number_of_sequences = 1000
sequence_length = 20
input = tf.random.uniform([number_of_sequences, sequence_length, features], dtype=tf.float32)
output = new_model(input) # shape is (number_of_sequences, sequence_length, features)
predicted = output[:,-1] # shape is (number_of_sequences, 1, features)
```

Shape of (32, 2) means that your sequence length is 32.

Batch size is a parameter of training (how many sequences should be feeded to the model before backpropagating error - see stochastic graient descent method). It doesn't affect your data (which shoud be 3-d - (number of sequences, length of sequence, feature)).

If you need to predict only one sequence - just feed tensor of shape (1, 20, 2) to the model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this solves it, but just to confirm before I accept your answer since your forgot the parameter, this works for `stateful=True` right?

Comment: Actually an extra question: when you say 'sequence', do you mean 'batch'? I'm new to this "Time Series Forecasting" so excuse my inexpertise.

Comment: Sorry - don't understand. Sequence is [[0, 1], [2, 3] ...]. Batch is a parameter of training: you can set it when calling 'fit()'